# Get pending messages with Redis Streams and Spring Data

Tags: kotlin, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-streams

I use Redis Streams in my Spring Boot application. Within a scheduler I regularly want to get all the pending messages and check how long they are already processing and re-trigger them if necessary.

My problem is now that I can get the pending messages, but I'm not sure how to get the payload.

My first approach used the `pending` and `range` operations. The downside here is that the totalDeliveryCount is not increased with `range` - so I cannot use the range method

```
val pendingMessages = stringRedisTemplate.opsForStream<String, Any>().pending(redisStreamName, Consumer.from(redisConsumerGroup, instanceName))
return pendingMessages.filter { pendingMessage ->
    if (pendingMessage.totalDeliveryCount < maxDeliveryAttempts && pendingMessage.elapsedTimeSinceLastDelivery > Duration.ofMillis(pendingTimeout.toLong())) {
            return@filter true
    } else {
        ...
        return@filter false
    }
}.map { //map from PendingMessage::class to a MapRecord with the content
    val map = stringRedisTemplate.opsForStream().range(redisStreamName, Range.just(it.idAsString)) // does not increase totalDeliveryCount !!!
    if (map != null && map.size > 0) { 
        return@map map[0]
    } else {
        return@map null
    }
}.filterNotNull().toList()
```

My second approach used the `pending` and `read` operations. For the read operation I can specify an offset with the current ID. The problem is that I only get IDs back which are higher then the one specified.

```
val pendingMessages = stringRedisTemplate.opsForStream().pending(redisStreamName, Consumer.from(redisConsumerGroup, instanceName))
return pendingMessages.filter { pendingMessage ->
    if (pendingMessage.totalDeliveryCount < maxDeliveryAttempts && pendingMessage.elapsedTimeSinceLastDelivery > Duration.ofMillis(pendingTimeout.toLong())) {
            return@filter true
    } else {
        ...
        return@filter false
    }
}.map { //map from PendingMessage::class to a MapRecord with the content
    val map = stringRedisTemplate.opsForStream<String, Any>()
            .read(it.consumer, StreamReadOptions.empty().count(1),
                    StreamOffset.create(redisStreamName, ReadOffset.from(it.id)))
    if (map != null && map.size > 0 && map[0].id.value == it.idAsString) { // map[0].id.value == it.idAsString does not match
        return@map map[0]
    } else {
        return@map null
    }
}.filterNotNull().toList()
```

So when I use `ReadOffset.from('1234-0')` I don't get the message with `1234-0` but everything after that message. Is there a way to get the exact message and also honoring the `totalDeliveryCount` and `elapsedTimeSinceLastDelivery` statistic?

I'm using spring-data-redis 2.3.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using following workaround now, which should be good for most cases:

```
return if (id.sequence > 0) {
            "${id.timestamp}-${id.sequence - 1}"
        } else {
            "${id.timestamp - 1}-99999"
        }
```

It relies on the fact that there are not more then 99999 messages inserted per ms.